# PHP Relative Time

Tags: php, time, web

Hello I have a question about relative time formats in PHP.  I am looking to get the time "month to date."  For example, Today is May 5th, I would like to get the time span from May 1st, to May 5th.  I tried using the format "this month," but I did not have success.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: please give some details

Comment: all general Date/Time related question have been answered before. Please ask something specific and/or use the Search function.

Comment: Yes strtotime() is what I am using, but when I try to use "this month," to get the time span back to the beginning of the month, I have no luck.

Comment: Sorry, maybe there should be a list of question that you cannot ask on this site

Comment: @Scientific such a list can be found in the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and there is a number of suggestions on how to ask better questions in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 0):

Will `strtotime()` work for you? It takes a string such as `next month` and then creates a timestamp of it.

If not, take a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342247/best-way-to-work-with-timespans).

Another option would be using `DateTime` which is builtin to PHP as well.